# VBScript to get information from Outlook (without any AD!)

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I am here with a question about scripting Outlook. Well, let me first start with *what I'd like to accomplish*:

- I would like to write a script that does the following with Outlook:

  1. Get all **Names (Users)** written under File > Info > Account Settings > Delegate Access, including the **Permissions...**
  2. Get all **Data Files** written under File > Info > Account Settings > Account Settings > Data Files
  3. Get currently used **Signatures** under Home > New E-mail > Signature and there the selection under **New messages:** and **Replies/forwards:**
  4. Finally, get all **Additional Mailboxes** under File > Info > Account Settings > Data Files > Settings... > Advanced > Mailboxes

*What's my skill level*?
I kind of got this task by accident, so not very high concerning the understanding of the Windows/ Office architecture. My background is R/ Matlab, Maple and some Mathematica and recently VBA. I've just started with VBScripting ;)

*What do I have so far*?
Almost nothing, but I do not ask for much. I don't need a full solution to the problem. Being creative will help me to build the code around your answers, hopefully! So far, I've managed to restore given *.psts, like this:

```
Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMAPI = oOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
WScript.Sleep 3000
```

and then ...

```
' Restore *.psts
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

    If UCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "PST" Then

        oMAPI.AddStore sPath & "\" & oFile.Name
        WScript.Sleep 500
    End If
Next
```

But let me step back a little. It is very important to know that I am a rookie with this :), but I can build all the code around. Writing from experience, I think that I would be happy with one line of code for every question (if that is possible), like:

```
???.Delegates.Names.Item(integer)
oMAPI.GetStore ...
???.MailItem.Signature.NewMessage.ToString() ' or whatever
oMAPI.AdditionalMailbox.Item(integer)
```

The four examples above are pure guessing, but I really couldn't find anything usable for me in the internet. It would be cool if most of the methods would return a string, so that I could log them into a text file.

I am glad about any answer, regardless of the Outlook version you are using. I've searched the Internet for two days and literally came up with nothing much but the short code above. I need some better starting points to proceed. And also, all things happen locally. I don't search for any AD solutions (like creating fancy automated AD signatures ...).

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That information is only accessing through the Exchange Web Services (EWS) API.
2. Use the Namespace.Stores collection
3. You can only access that information through the file system
4. Same as 2, but you will need to check the Store.ExchangeStoreType property to be olAdditionalExchangeMailbox (=4).

Comment: OK, I just checked your profile. 15 years of experience :) thank you, sir ... I got the points 2-3 now and I am going to try the point 1. I hope to come up with a solution without any ... APIs. Thanks again